# How to write/read binary data (in type) in Nim?

Tags: file, io, nim-lang

Assume I've got this data type:

```
type
  TODO* = tuple
    atTime: float
    item: string

type
  TestData* = tuple
    timeAdded: float
    who: string
    todo: seq[TODO]
    isDone: bool


var data: TestData
# code which sets and adds stuff in/to data
```

So the length will vary because of the seq.
Is there a direct way to save/load this data ?
Something like:
writeFile("testdata.dat", data) and later on readFile("testdata.dat", data) ?
I only find string and openArray for writeFile.  But readFile is only for a string plus when reading we won't know the number of bytes to read, unless we make dataBytes (the first) variable in the struct, so we know how many bytes to read.

Haven't tried because the string won't be convertible to the TestData type.  There was a question here with tuples of (float, float), solved with streams, but that data structure was simple(r).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that data types like strings or sequences are value types, that contain a (hidden) pointer to the actual heap-allocated data. So data types, that contain again strings or sequences, are not simple blobs, which can be written to disk with a single operation. For strings, and for sequences that have plain object types as base types, like seq[float], we could write a single binary blob. In that case, for a seq, we could use addr myseq[0] as start of the blob, and myseq.len*sizeof(typeof(myseq[0])) would give us the size of the blob. Of course, before reading that blob, we would have to allocate the data buffer, e.g. with something like mySeq = newSeq[myBaseType](blobSizeOnDisk div sizeof(mybasetype)). This is just for you to get a feeling for the problem, I know that it is not really helpful for your actual issue. For the serialization of non-trivial data, Nim has many libraries like JSON serialization. These libs can handle most nested data types, as long as the element types are static and known at compile time. As far as I know, all libs have some problems when we use sequences of ref objects, and the ref objects have various actual types as runtime. When you do not want to use human-readable JSON (or YAML or TOML) format, you may search for the term "binary serialization". I think Nim has a few libs for that, but I never used one of them, sorry.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, thinking of it more (while I should have been asleep), I also came to the conclusion that JSON might be the way to do it.  I already use that for loading/saving settings.  In my case binary serialization might be better, so I'll have a look at YAML and TOML.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the YAML lib uses human-readable text for storing data, and I assume TOML libs as well. But Nim has libraries for serialization in binary format, at least as external packages. Just do a nimble or Google search, or consult the list of curated Nim packages (awesome Nim). And note that additionally to the JSON lib of Nim' standard library, there are many more: From Status.im, from Mr. Treeform, and a few more.

Comment: Yeah, I use jsony by Treeform.  Human readable doesn't bother too much.  Only, sometimes it tempts a user to go editing it : one misplaced comma and hell may break loose...